# How should I not load the images with broken link?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I'm working on a feature, in which images are being rendered from the servers. I was working on aligning the images but found that there is a lot of white space. This was the reason, due to loading of images with a broken link.

[image]

HTML :

```
<div class="image-result" *ngIf="Display('images')">
    <div class="col-sm-3" *ngFor="let item of items$|async">
      <a href="{{item.link}}">
          <figure>
             <img class="res-img" src="{{item.link}}" onerror="this.style.display='none'">
          </figure>       
      </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have used `onerror="this.style.display='none'"` to solve the problem, but leaves a lot of white space when images are being loaded from the server. Is there any solution for it like to remove img tag whenever a image with a broken link has been detected ? I have gone through stackoverflow before asking question, but I'm not able to solve this problem. It would be great if someone can help me out. Thanks! :)

Comment: You can use `*ngIf` to conditionally add or remove elements from your view.

Comment: @abhishekkannojia I didn't understood it. I'm already using `*ngIf` in parent `div`

Answer (score 4):

Instead of `onerror="this.style.display='none'"` to hide an image, you can use `onerror="this.parentNode.removeChild(this)"` to remove the image tag altogether.

---

If you want to remove the entire column, in your specific case you can do the following.

```
var colEl = this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
colEl.parentNode.removeChild(colEl);
```

Or, in your HTML:

```
onerror="this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode)"
```

You should probably move that to some JavaScript function and attach your handler by saying

```
element.addEventListener('error', function() { /* ... */ });
```

References: [`parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode), [`removeChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild), [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

---

If you don't care about supporting Internet Explorer, you can also use [`remove`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove) instead of doing the `parentNode.removeChild` trickery. That would be particularly useful for reducing the code length in your `onerror` attribute, would you choose to use it, but I don't recommend that.

Comment: The removal part is explained better here. this is the answer i was about to post also :D . Documentation here for remove(examples) http://red-team-design.com/removing-an-element-with-plain-javascript-remove-method/

Comment: Wouldn't this still leave the white space - if hiding it with `display:none` doesn't work then removing it won't either surely? Think you would either need to remove it at the link or div level depending on the styles

Comment: @Pete no - hiding an element makes it invisible - if a div is hidden but has a min-height and width attribute, it will take up that space. Removing an element removes it from the DOM so it doesn't exist anymore - thus no space used

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs the above is only removing the image and by using display none on the image that is the same as removing it as it will take up no space - if the div is still being rendered with `col-sm-3` then it will still be taking up that width that is causing the white space.  If you hide it with visibility instead of display, then and only then will it still take up space - https://jsfiddle.net/5uojfa61/1

Comment: @Pete ah no you're right - it's when `display: none` is used and there's whitespace in the actual code is when it adds spacing and stuff

Comment: Hey! thanks for giving time to my question. But your solution is not working. :/

Comment: @Harshit I finally had some time to update my answer. Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 1):

A more angular-way of doing this would be:

```
 <img src="{{item.link}}" (error)="item.brokenImage=true">
```

So you would have:

```
<div class="col-sm-3" *ngFor="let item of items$|async">
    <div *ngIf="!item.brokenImage">
        <a href="{{item.link}}">
            <figure>
                <img class="res-img" [src]="item.link" (error)="item.brokenImage=true">
            </figure>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

You need to listen for the error event of the image element, and assign a boolean on whether the image loaded successfully or not. Then, depending on that value angular will either show the image with the div, or remove it from the DOM.

Comment: Thanks for giving time to my question. :) I really appreciated your help. It would be great if you can provide me complete solution for it. I have changed the `img` tag line with the above solution you have provided me. But it seems to be not working :/

Comment: I have edited my post. Try that. If it doesn't work, can you let me know if you're getting any errors?

Comment: Can we use `*ngIf` and `*ngFor` together ? I did some changes again according to your answer, now the whole page does not load. Also, what is `brokenImage` here? Is it a feature in angular ?

Comment: It's possible angular requires the ng-if to be after the ng-for condition. It is possible to use both of them together. brokenImage is a variable you use to specify whether or not the image loaded. It's not an angular feature, it's just a variable that you can name whatever you want which serves to know whether or not the image loaded successfully or not.

Comment: Hmm. Is there any other solution ? Because, I'm trying solve it since morning. I'm struck only in this part.

Comment: What error are you getting? Can you look in the console and see if anything pops out?

Comment: `Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
Can't have multiple template bindings on one element.` and `ResultsComponent@37:60
Can't bind to 'ng-src' since it isn't a known property of 'img'.` These are the console errors.

Comment: I've edited the post again. That should fix the two issues you're having.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144063/discussion-between-harshit-and-dragos-paul-marinescu).